# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We use firestore several years, and have some SnapshotListener works perfectly till recently caught this exception:

```
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException.forApiException(FirestoreException.java:104)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.Watch$2.run(Watch.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.Watch$2.run(Watch.java:348)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:67)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:82)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onError(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:86)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:553)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:68)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:739)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:718)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    ... 17 more
```

Code:

```
Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(); 
db.collection("collectionname").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() { });
```

I've already search for the solutions, but didn't find any good solutions...

Comment: What is the code that produces that error?

Comment: `Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();`
`db.collection("collectionname").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {`
`});`

Comment: Still working with Firebase support to find out the root cause...

Comment: Update: from Google Support, "it seems like the latest Admin SDK (8.1.0) is not using the latest BOM version for the GCP Firestore Java SDK (25.2.0) I will engage the Firebase team to look into this."

Comment: It seems like Firebase team fix this problem, I tested version 9.0.0 (release on 2022/6/16) and there is no this kind of problem.

Comment: Good news, Mark ;)